# How do you correctly post to 2 similar forms individually from within the same view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This seems to be a fairly common question that I have seen here on stackoverflow, but nobody seems to have the answer that I am looking for.  I have 2 forms (the standard user login and the register form) that I would like on the same view.  It works correctly if everything goes well, but if theirs a failure and the form re-posts 2 undesirable things happen:

1. Both forms attempt to validate though only one was filled out.
2. The id for the 'username' input is the same on both forms, so data entered into one is populated in both.

I'm not sure what it is that I need to understand about validation to make this work correctly, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">      </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@{Html.RenderPartial("LogIn",  (FortyEightHourPrint.Models.LogOnModel)ViewBag.LogInModel);}
@{Html.RenderPartial("Register", (FortyEightHourPrint.Models.RegisterModel)ViewBag.RegisterModel);}
```

and the register partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register","Account")) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor((m => m.UserName))
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

and the login

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn","Account"))
{
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
}
```

and of course the stuff that the controller is doing

```
   public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        if ((bool)(ViewBag.OkToRedirect ?? false))
            return Redirect(getReturnUrl(ViewBag.ReturnUrl));
        return View();
    }
   public PartialViewResult LogIn()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    //
    // POST: /Account/LogIn

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult LogIn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.OkToRedirect = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                ViewBag.OkToRedirect = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.LogInModel = model;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View("LogOn");
    }


    public PartialViewResult Register()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Register(RegisterModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.OkToRedirect = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                ViewBag.OkToRedirect = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        ViewBag.RegisterModel = model;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View("LogOn");
    }
```

Also, I am new to mvc, so if anybody can suggest a better approach I am all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add these extension methods to some class:

   ```
   public static IDisposable BeginFieldPrefix<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
       Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expression)
   {
       return BeginFieldPrefix(html, (LambdaExpression) expression);
   }

   internal static IDisposable BeginFieldPrefix(this HtmlHelper html, LambdaExpression expression)
   {
       return BeginFieldPrefix(html, html.GetName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
   }

   public static IDisposable BeginFieldPrefix(this HtmlHelper html, string fieldPrefix)
   {
       var templateInfo = html.ViewData.TemplateInfo;
       string oldFieldPrefix = templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
       templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = fieldPrefix;
       return Disposable.Create(() => templateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = oldFieldPrefix);
   }

   public static string GetName<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
   {
       return html.GetName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
   }

   public static string GetName(this HtmlHelper html, string expression)
   {
       return html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expression);
   }
   ```

`Disposable` class is located in Rx Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.disposable(v=vs.103).aspx

1. Use the following code inside your `BeginForm` block to prefix all fields:

   @using(Html.BeginFieldPrefix("LoginForm")) {
       ...
   }

   @using(Html.BeginFieldPrefix("RegisterForm")) {
       ...
   }
2. Use `UpdateModel` and `TryUpdateModel` overload allowing to specify field prefix instead of implicit model update (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493137.aspx ).

Comment: Thanks for these Alex. just haveing a couple problems with it, what includes do I need for Disposable? and GetName doesn't seem to exist, is that another extension method?

Comment: I just added `GetName` to above code, and a bit modified it to use `Disposable` class from Rx Framework. So it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently run into the same problem, where validation fires on multiples forms because they contain the same field names.

[This post](http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/MBest/archive/2010/01/19/833.aspx) helped me out alot.

Hope this helps,

Matt

Comment: That was a great post! Great information, and it addressed all possible issues.